# Soccer offside by interfering with an opponent?

Tags: rules, football, fifa

When a player in an offside position makes any move to allow a goal to be scored, after a deflection of an opponent, should the goal be allowed or not and why?

Answer (score 3):

According to [IFAB's Laws of the Game 2019/20](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/files/document-category/062019/frRhKJNjSBAtiyt.pdf)

The goal should not be allowed if:

> Law 11
>   2. Offside offence
>   ...
>   Interfering with an opponent by:
>   • preventing an opponent from playing or being able to play the ball by clearly obstructing the opponent’s line of vision or
>   • challenging an opponent for the ball or
>   • clearly attempting to play a ball which is close when this action impacts
>   on an opponent or
>   • making an obvious action which clearly impacts on the ability of an opponent to play the ball